# Deleting rows in numpy array between boundaries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like:

```
a = np.array([1.2,10],[2.3,20],[3.4,30],[4.5,40],[5.8,50],[6.7,60],[7.8,70],[8.9,80])
```

Now i want to check the first column and delete everything thats smaller than 3 and bigger than 6. That means i want my array to look like:

```
a = np.array([3.4,30],[4.5,40],[5.8,50])
```

The problem is i can't use `np.delete()` to manually delete the rows because i dont know the amount of the rows.

Do i have to iterate, or is there a simple way?

Comment: `numpy.array` requires an iterable, not an arbitrary amount of arguments.

Comment: You probably want to encapsulate that list as a lists of lists... i.e. `np.array([[1.2,10]...,[8.9,80]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to delete, you want to select. This is how you can go about it:

```
a = np.array([[1.2,10],[2.3,20],[3.4,30],[4.5,40],[5.8,50],[6.7,60],[7.8,70],[8.9,80]])
a[(a[:,0]>=3) & (a[:,0]<=6)]

Out: array([[  3.4,  30. ],
   [  4.5,  40. ],
   [  5.8,  50. ]])
```